# Beautifulsoup: how to get certain link from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web-scraping

With BeautifulSoup how would one get the links from a webpage, store them in a list, then print out a certain one?
This is what I have so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://example.com/")
content = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
for link in content.find_all("a"):
    print(link.get("href")[0])
```

But I get this error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` How can I solve this problem and get the first link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve all links from a page, use regex.

The following code should do it for you:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("https://www.stmaryottumwa.org/")
content = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
links = []

for link in content.find_all("a", attrs={'href': re.compile("^http")}):
    links.append(link.get("href"))

print(links[0]) # print first link on page
```

The variable links will contain all the links on the page.

Comment: The list is of each letter in the link. Not each link. When I do `[0]` it returns `h`,  when I do `[1]` it returns `t`,  when I do `[2]` it returns `t`, and so on. How do I fix this so it prints the whole link?

Comment: If you want to print the first link, change the last line to ```print(links[0])```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the element's attributes you need to access the `.attrs` dict.
Also keep in mind that sometimes `a` tags do not have an `href` attribute at all, you can get around that by using `.get`:

```
link.attrs.get('href')
```

I'm not sure what you expected `[0]` to do since an `a` tag can only have a single `href` attribute. Using `[0]` will get you the first **character** of the `href` attribute.

```
for link in content.find_all("a"):
    href = a.attrs.get('href')
    if href:
        print(href[0])
```

Comment: `print(link.attrs['href'][0])` returns `KeyError: 'href'` error. Any ideas?

Comment: It happens when `a` tag doesn't have `href` attribute, you can resolve it using `try/except` block

Comment: @DeepSpace OK, but now I get this: `print(link.attrs.get('href', '')[1])
IndexError: string index out of range`, when I do this `print(link.attrs.get('href', '')[0])`

Comment: @Alen See again... you need to make sure it actually exists before you inspect the first character. But again, I'm not sure why you even do this. If you want the entire link, just `print(href)`

Comment: @DeepSpace I wanted to get the very first link. I thought that `[0]` would do that

Comment: @Alen Again, like I wrote in the answer. There can only ever be a single value for the `href` attribute